# Need help building a system with multiple back-up drives

Tags: hard-drive

I have built and set up many systems but I had a new request that I have never had to deal with. Let me explain what they want to do with the system and see if you can answer how I should do it.

A friend of mine is working with a school in a class about photography. They want the system set up with a main drive (C Drive - 1TB), a work drive (D Drive - 2TB), final picture drive (E Drive - 2Tb), and a drive to store picture sets (F Drive - 2TB). Now, they want an external drive system set up to back up all of these drive except the work drive, twice over. I am thinking I need to set up a 5 bay drive external enclosure (Drives G - k). Can I set it up to have C drive back-up to G, E Drive back-up to H & J, and F drive back-up to I & K? If not a back-up, can I have it as something changes on the C drive that a mirror copy will automatically write to the G Drive? and so forth?

Thanks for your help, Danial Barncord

Comment: why not use cloud solutions? they will be cheaper to support and faster to install. However, you should google "how to backup <YOUR OS NAME HERE> OS" for info on backing up "C" drive.

Comment: What is the purpose for backing up twice?  There are online backup services are redundant enough that you wouldn't need two backups of everything.  They can also be version controlled to restore back to the day / hour as needed.  If they are that paranoid about loosing something, maybe worth looking into.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need Help Setting Up A Raid 10 Array](http://superuser.com/questions/1045621/need-help-setting-up-a-raid-10-array)

Answer (score 1):

For these requirements, I would not bother trying to isolate the backups on different disks.

Assuming a very limited setup, I would get two 6TB disks, install them as G and H, and then install/configure CrashPlan (free) to backup C, E, and F to G as one backup, and to H as a second backup, both every 6 hours.

Ideally, drives G and H would be in a different server connected over the network, and I would use CrashPlan's online backup service to store a copy of the backup off-site to protect against lightning strikes or floods that could cause all the drives to fail.